# How to average several columns at once in Scalding?

Tags: hadoop, cascading, scalding

As the final step on some computations with Scalding I want to compute several averages of the columns in a pipe. But the following code doesn't work

```
myPipe.groupAll { _average('col1,'col2, 'col3) }
```

Is there any way to compute such functions `sum, max, average` without doing several passes? I'm concerned about performance but maybe Scalding is smart enough to detect that programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was answered in the [cascading-user](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cascading-user/YTKQdhJJeBI) forum. Leaving an answer here as a reference

```
myPipe.groupAll { _.average('col1).average('col2).average('col3) }
```

Comment: Use round braces if you want it in one line. `myPipe.groupAll(_.average('col1).average('col2).average('col3))`. Curly braces should expand to 3 lines.

Comment: @ancehu How would this be achieved in Cascading?

Answer (score 1):

you can do size (aka count), average, and standardDev in one go using the function below.

```
// Find the count of boys vs. girls, their mean age and standard deviation. 
// The new pipe contains "sex", "count", "meanAge" and "stdevAge" fields.
val demographics = people.groupBy('sex) { _.sizeAveStdev('age -> ('count, 'meanAge, 'stdevAge) ) }
```

finding max would require another pass though.